# Separating Uppercase From Numbers In CSV File

Tags: python, string, csv, uppercase

I have a large csv file with numbers and letters in the same row.

How can I get in a new column only the uppercase letters?

CSV has this format

```
1AAOIAppli
2ABEOAbeon
3ABIOARCA
4ABUSArbut
5ACERAcer

...
```

And I would like to generate a new csv like this

```
AAOI
ABEO
ABIO
ABUS
ACER
...
```

Been learning python for the last 2 weeks and I am desperate with this,

Thank you all

Comment: It seems that you are not looking to get only the uppercase letters, but that you are looking to get the four characters after the comma. You can use the `split` method, first, to get what's before and after the comma, and second simply use `[:4]` to get the first four characters.

Comment: What have you done so far? What results are you getting? What have you done to debug your code?

Comment: Hello Rajesh, thank you for your reply, I can not apply the split first because the number is not separeted with a coma. Do I have to use something to recognize only the text in it and not the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

### Using `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

# read in the file
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)

# .isupper to check a character
# .join to join the letters back into a string
# [:4] to slice the first 4
df['upper'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: ''.join([letter for letter in x if letter.isupper()])[:4])

print(df)

          0 upper
 1AAOIAppli  AAOI
 2ABEOAbeon  ABEO
  3ABIOARCA  ABIO
 4ABUSArbut  ABUS
  5ACERAcer  ACER

# save only upper to a new file
df['upper'].to_csv('new_file.csv', index=False)
```

### If you want all the uppercase letters instead of the first 4

```py
df['upper'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: ''.join([letter for letter in x if letter.isupper()]))

          0     upper
 1AAOIAppli     AAOIA
 2ABEOAbeon     ABEOA
  3ABIOARCA  ABIOARCA
 4ABUSArbut     ABUSA
  5ACERAcer     ACERA
```